# How do i make a COMPLETE BOOTABLE iso of my system?

Tags: backup, iso, debian

Exactly as the title posts. I want to make a completely bootable iso of my system incase something breaks. Not just the files but the whole system!

Answer (score 0):

Look at CloneZilla (http://clonezilla.org/) to make an image of your hard drive. You can then dump that image onto another HDD and boot it just like it was the original.

NOTE: The second drive has to be at least as big as the original drive.

Comment: Clonezilla: nice program, but mind its limitations.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: I just refer to some of the limitations mentioned on the homepage of Clonezilla. E.g. no online imaging, the partition to be imaged has to be unmounted. Or multiple DVDs is not implemented yet.